# CSS - Styled border leaders

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style borders to start a css border with a leader AND finish a percentage through the width.

Basically i need to build a responsive version of below (**ideally which would work in ie8 also**)

[image]

So the border begins/ends with a square and finishes 60% of the way through the bottom section

it needs to be responsive vertically and ideally horizontally also. My only idea is to use a combo of image and border - so the bottom border has a white background image ending at the square and a border line running though it?  Thinking there must be a better way to do this though?

any ideas!?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about HTML and CSS rather than programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt this is IE compatible--especially back to 8, but it was a fun exercise, and maybe it will give you some ideas. **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qiqomu/1/edit)**

The basic strategy is to use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to position your bullet and, in the case of the `:after` element, to cover up part of the container's bottom border.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a euismod libero. Fusce tincidunt, urna id pulvinar consectetur, nibh lacus faucibus risus, nec varius nisi dolor in sem. Etiam et elementum ligula, sed porta nisl. Sed luctus maximus tortor, in malesuada felis pharetra eu. Donec ultrices urna ultrices lectus venenatis egestas. Suspendisse nec orci vestibulum, ullamcorper dolor sit amet, pulvinar risus. Integer semper hendrerit mi at sodales.</p>
  <a href="#">Find out more</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  border-top: .15rem solid #ccc;
  border-right: .15rem solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: .15rem solid #ccc;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.container:after,
.container:before {
  content: '■';
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.container:before {
  top: -.55rem;
  left: -.5rem;
}

.container:after {
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -.55rem;
  right: 60%;
}

.container p {
  text-align: left;
}

.container a {
  color: #ee0;
}
```

Comment: with a bit of tweaking it works a treat - nice one fella

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a hacky way:

HTML:

```
<div class="top"><div class="square"></div></div>
<div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div class="square"></div><div class="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background-color: #999;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: -10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.top {
    height: 4px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.top .square {
    margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}

.content {
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

.bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ohxe3ck6/1/